# Custom HTTP Handler Not Working in IIS 7 and above & Integrated Mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I'm creating a custom image handler to handle all *.jpg requests.   What is the difference in IIS between

> Add Script Map

and

> Add Managed Handle

Which one should I use?   It seems I don't need all the overhead of the ASP.NET framework since my entire application is only handling image output.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two are:

- Script Maps - used to map requests to "native code" handlers, i.e. code that *isn't* managed code, for example C#/VB.NET. This is a legacy feature so that you can map requests to native code executables or dll's that comply with the CGI spec. An example of this would be mapping `*.pl` to a Perl interpreter.
- Managed Handlers - these are used to map requests to "managed code". For example writing handlers using C# or VB.NET.

So if your custom image handler is written in one of the many .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, Managed C++, etc) then you'll need to add a Managed Handler.

Comment: I have created my handler with ASP.Net web application project and I have created class file for handler inside my App_Code folder. It is working fine now. However now I am wonder thing that how can I make this thing work without entire ASP.Net structure?

Comment: @user2789150 - So the only ASP.NET code in your site is the handler?

Comment: Yes Kev, I have created separate site for it.

Comment: @user2789150 - You should just be able to copy the output binary from the `bin` folder after building and throw it into a `/bin` folder in your site.

Comment: Kev Thanks for your help.  Isn’t there a more ideal way to compile this managed handler without me creating it like a website and stealing just the bin folder?  Besides, I still have a web.config file which seems strange and it is there where I have set the handler information and so far I haven’t needed to create a Managed Handler through IIS.  It seems that I must be doing something wrong and still bringing in the overhead of ASP.NET which is not needed.

Comment: @user2789150 - sorry, I missed your last comment. I'd say I have technically answered this particular question "What is the difference between *Add Script Map*...". So maybe you can click the tick and accept this :). I will try to address your other concerns which you've expanded on in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025514