# Custom HTTP Handler for images

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I'm creating a custom image handler to handle all *.jpg requests. I would like to register it in IIS 7 & above by Add Manage Handler. I have two choices:

Create a separate ASP.Net web application project and create a class under App_Code folder which contains only handler code. In this way by adding handler to web.config I would be able to register handler into IIS.

OR

Create a class library project without entire ASP.Net structure. In this way I need to use IIS interface and manually register managed handler.

Question is which way is better? Can I avoid overhead of entire ASP.Net Framework by just creating class library project?

Comment: You should be aware of the rejected changes to your post [from this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3018777). You can always edit your post with more information, including suggestions from the link.

Comment: Given an HTTP handler is just a .NET class plus an element in the `web.config` you need to look at the larger context to make this kind of choice. One significantr advantage of the first option is it gives you the debugging setup of an ASP.NET application that would otherwise require project file editing.

Comment: @Richard - Thanks, Where I was really wondering is can I avoid overhead of ASP.Net framework by just creating a class library, compile it and register that DLL as managed handler in IIS? Because if I go with choice one in IIS DLL for managed handler is showing up ISAPI DLL.

Comment: I don't whether it is possible to create an ISAPI DLL in .NET without some native (ie. C/C++) proxy layer. Otherwise, in IIS7 and beyond, thwere is almost no "ASP.NET overhead" since IIS directly integrates with ASP.NET (read up on "integrated pipeline").